# Docker with lerna (Next.js and Graphql)

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, npm, next.js

so I am using lerna and everything works fine on local but when I try to build the image and run it through docker it seems to be not working as supposed to

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11
ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm i -g lerna
RUN lerna bootstrap
CMD npm run dev:all
```

this is the Dockerfile and this is the dockerignore file

```
node_modules
packages/api/node_modules
packages/web/node_modules
packages/web/.next
```

this the project structure I have ( using npm workspaces with lerna [so I can run stuff parallely] )
[image]

when I try to run the image/spin the container ( sorry if the terms are not right I am fairly new to Docker nd my first time using it ) this the output I get

```
 docker run locus

> dev:all
> lerna run --parallel dev

lerna notice cli v4.0.0
lerna info Executing command in 2 packages: "npm run dev"
api: > api@1.0.0 dev
api: > ts-node-dev --respawn -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts
web: > web@1.0.0 dev
web: > next dev
web: ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
web: info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
api: [INFO] 17:31:43 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.8 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.3.5)
api: Error: Cannot find module 'tsconfig-paths/register'
api: Require stack:
api: - internal/preload
api:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927:15)
api:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:772:27)
api:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
api:     at Module._preloadModules (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1247:12)
api:     at loadPreloadModules (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:468:5)
api:     at prepareMainThreadExecution (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:75:3)
api:     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:7:1
web: It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.
web: Please install typescript by running:
web:    npm install --save-dev typescript
web: If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files in your pages directory).
lerna ERR! npm run dev exited 1 in 'web'
lerna ERR! npm run dev stdout:

> web@1.0.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
lerna ERR! npm run dev stderr:
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have the required package(s) installed.

Please install typescript by running:

        npm install --save-dev typescript

If you are not trying to use TypeScript, please remove the tsconfig.json file from your package root (and any TypeScript files in your pages directory).

lerna ERR! npm run dev exited 1 in 'web'
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 1 child process to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
```

I am not sure if it's the way I have structured my project or something else ( errors happen when I do `npm install` too also I have typescript and tsconfig-paths as dev deps already )

Comment: Did you try adding `RUN npm install` before your `RUN lerna bootstrap`?

Comment: No I didn't I just replace `lerna bootstrap` with `npm install` lemme try :D

Answer (score 1):

just put the `ENV NODE_ENV=production` after the bootstrapping, since the production env will cause npm to skip all dev dependencies, which might be required for building your app.

The best practice would be to have separate stages, one for build with dev-deps and one for the finished container without dev-dependencies.